# Ubuntu boots to GRUB menu and starting Ubuntu leads to black screen

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a System76 laptop that came pre-installed with Ubuntu.  I have used this laptop for about 1 year now.  It has had no problems and is currently running Ubuntu 13.10.  I turned the laptop on today and it booted to GRUB menu.  When I choose booting Ubuntu or any of the advanced options it goes to a black screen with the fan running.

It worked fine the yesterday and I don't believe I have installed anything new.  I would like to give you more information but I'm not able to get any output from it.  I've tried Recovery Mode but I do not know what to put into the Command Line.

If you have any ideas I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!!

Edit: I cannot open up a terminal.  Deleting quiet and splash, or adding in nomodeset, still leads to a black screen.  I have NVIDIA, but have been using it for a year.  The only things that work are using CLTR+ALT+DEL to reboot and I can turn of the screen, using Fn+F2.

Comment: You can check out this link that has lots on repairing grub. http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: Is it a completely black screen or do you still see a blinking white underline character at the top of the black screen by way of a prompt?

Comment: It is completely black and does not respond to any typing.  Except Cltr+Alt+Del will restart the computer back to the GRUB menu