# Windows shutdown leads to grub menu and Ubuntu shutdown leads to blank screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am using a dual boot system of Windows 10 and ubuntu 21.04 with grub 2.04 loader. Hardware is ASUS TUF FX505 laptop.

After about usage for 400 power cycles with this setup, I encountered an error while shutting down from windows or ubuntu.

The specific problem is that when I power off from Windows 10, I get led to the grub 2.04 menu instead of complete power off.

Also when I power off from Ubuntu 21.04, I get led to just a blank screen, which demands me to press the power button on the keyboard to really power off the system.

how to resolve this issue? is it a hw or sw issue?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/430561/ubuntu-boots-to-grub-menu-and-starting-ubuntu-leads-to-black-screen is a similar problem, may help me resolve the second part.

Comment: The specific problem is that when I power off from Windows 10, I get led to the grub 2.04 menu instead of complete power off.

Comment: You don't need to reply to the bot. That message appears when someone reviewing the question consideres it lacks details or clarity. In any case, repeating verbatim what you already posted in the question adds and clarifies absolutely nothing.

Comment: Ahhh okay I did not see that it was a bot. Will try to breath in more specificity into the question by editing it out. Please bear with me.